# jQuery Add then remove width to consecutive elements in a loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

OK so once a page has finished loading, I want to add a width to a group of elements, one after the other in a loop.

Example:

```
<div id="container-wrap">

   <div id="container"></div>
   <div id="container"></div>
   <div id="container"></div>
   <div id="container"></div>
   <div id="container"></div>

</div>
```

So it would add the width to the first element, then remove then move on to the second element, so on and so forth.

Then once it gets to the last one, it starts over.

How would I do that?

Comment: You shouldn't have elements with the same id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited : my idea with deferreds didnt work , but in cycle you can add `.delay(..)` 
to delay animations on different elements accordingly

see jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/Yzpft/

```
 var containers = $('#container-wrap').find('.container') 

 containers.each(function(ind,el) {                   
      $(el).delay(800 * ind)
          .animate({'width': '400px'}, 400)  
          .animate({'width': '100px'}, 400)        
 })
```

Now if you need to constanly do it without delay and your number of element is constant you can use following code

```
 var containers = $('#container-wrap').find('.container') 
   , length = containers.length
   , interval = 800 * length
   , intervalVar = null

 function animate() {
    containers.each(function(ind,el) {                   
      $(el).delay(800 * ind)
          .animate({'width': '400px'}, 400)  
          .animate({'width': '100px'}, 400)        
    })
 })

 intervalVar = setInterval(animate, interval)

 ... and whenever you need to stop it 

 clearInterval(intervalVar)
```

Comment: It's not moving on to the next element, just does it to the first one.