# Fade In / Out Multiple Elements Using jQuery.when

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-deferred, promise

I have pairs of elements that need to start fading out / in at the same time. That is, both elements in a pair should only start to fade in when the fade-out is complete; and to fade out when fade-in is done.

I basically use `$.when` on both elements in a pair for both fade-in and fade-out. Basically, to wait until the fading completes. Is this correct? Anything **simpler than this solution**?

Complete code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sikusikucom/RruxA/)

```
$.when($('.next-' + id).fadeOut(500)).done(function () {
  var n = ...
  $.when($('.next-' + n).fadeIn(500)).done(function () {
    ...
  });
});
```

Also, `.fadeOut()` returns a jQuery object. How can we pass it into `$.when`, which expects a Deferred object? Help?

Comment: you can look at something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mGzLm/2/

Comment: Thanks @ArunPJohny, but that does not guarantee that `.fadeIn()` happens only after `.fadeOut()` is complete. For example, try setting `... fadeOut(50 * 1000).promise(), ... .fadeIn(0.8 * 1000).promise(), ...` i.e. really long fade out, really short fade in.

Answer (score 3):

You can exploit a feature of jQuery by which an animated jQuery collection will return a "promise of completion" with `.promise()` :

I think this is what you are trying to achieve :

```
$('.next-' + id).fadeOut(500).promise().then(function() {
    var n = ...;
    return $('.next-' + n).fadeIn(500).promise();
}).then(function() {
    ...
});
```

Note that by building a `.then()` chain in this way, we avoid a "[pyramid of doom](http://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/jquery/using-the-jquery-promise-interface-to-avoid-the-ajax-pyramid-of-doom/)".

Things get a bit trickier if you are using an custom animation queue, but for the standard `fx` queue (as in this case), everything is made very simple for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is simplier way. Just use `.delay(x)` See my answer to this question [jQuery Add then remove width to consecutive elements in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430764/jquery-add-then-remove-width-to-consecutive-elements-in-a-loop/16430794?noredirect=1#comment24757048_16430794) and your updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RruxA/1/

```
var MAX = 2;

var animateCard = function (id) {

  setInterval(function () {        
    var n = (id % MAX) + 1
    $('.next-' + id).fadeOut(500)
    $('.next-' + n).delay(500).fadeIn(800)
    id = n                          
  }, MAX * 1300);
}

animateCard(1);
```